# Azure External resizer is continuously failing

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kubernetes

The scenario is whenever the disk consumption of any of my ECK node goes above the watermark level, I resize the cluster in the object file's pvc (after exhausting all other option, of course) and new storage gets attached.
But recently, the azure csi external resizer is continuosly in the process of rresizing the pvc of one of my stateful set but is failing.

```
  ----    ------    ----                 ----                                 -------
  Normal  Resizing  87s (x408 over 13h)  external-resizer disk.csi.azure.com  External resizer is resizing volume pvc-4f319882-1ee8-44fb-b4cf-00737acc4d56
```

When I describe the PVC, it says:

> error setting resizer annotation to pvc. the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again.

What can I do regarding this?